# Sorting Dotted Numbers in JSON & PHP

Tags: php, json

In my project with PHP Inside the JSON is the data I keep. And each of these data has sequence numbers
1.1,
1.1.1,
1.1.2,
1.1.3,
...,
1.1.10.

When I sorted, I noticed that 1.1.10 came after 1.1.1, whereas 1.1.9 wasn't there yet.

Because it sorts alphabetically.
And I don't know how to deal with it!

Edit: Added sample JSON data.

```
{
  "2": {
    "sirano": "1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "124": {
    "sirano": "1.1.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "125": {
    "sirano": "1.1.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "126": {
    "sirano": "1.1.3",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "127": {
    "sirano": "1.1.4",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "128": {
    "sirano": "1.1.5",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "129": {
    "sirano": "1.1.6",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "130": {
    "sirano": "1.1.7",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "131": {
    "sirano": "1.1.8",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "132": {
    "sirano": "1.1.9",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "133": {
    "sirano": "1.1.10",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "134": {
    "sirano": "1.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "135": {
    "sirano": "1.3.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "136": {
    "sirano": "1.3.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "137": {
    "sirano": "1.4.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  }
}
```

[image: The ordering looks like this:]

```
$data = json_decode($proje->JSONData, true); 
function order($a, $b) 
{
    return $a['sirano'] - $b['sirano'];
}
uasort($data, 'order');
```

I tried like this, but the result is clear!
Please help me, I'm going crazy!

Comment: Use natsort() instead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort

Comment: Please always add sample data instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please do not show any pictures here. Show us PHP code or JSON embedded in code tags.

Comment: Sorry. I have attached the sample JSON data. Numeric sorting by key "sirano" is important to me...

Comment: @MarkusZeller natsort() use for only single dimensional arrays

Comment: These are NOT numbers. These are **strings**

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov What stops you using natsort() inside uasort()?

Comment: Loop stops me.)) Because your way increase iteration count.

Comment: My answer related directly question => version_compare. Why do we need difficult solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `version_compare` function inside of sort function:

```php
<?php

$json = json_decode('{
  "2": {
    "sirano": "1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "124": {
    "sirano": "1.1.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "125": {
    "sirano": "1.1.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "126": {
    "sirano": "1.1.3",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "127": {
    "sirano": "1.1.4",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "128": {
    "sirano": "1.1.5",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "129": {
    "sirano": "1.1.6",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "130": {
    "sirano": "1.1.7",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "131": {
    "sirano": "1.1.8",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "132": {
    "sirano": "1.1.9",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "133": {
    "sirano": "1.1.10",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "134": {
    "sirano": "1.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "135": {
    "sirano": "1.3.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "136": {
    "sirano": "1.3.2",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  },
  "137": {
    "sirano": "1.4.1",
    "personal": "4",
    "tarihler": {
      "baslangic": "2022-11-10",
      "bitis": "2022-11-17"
    },
    "ilerleme": "0"
  }
}',true);

function order($a, $b) 
{
    return version_compare($a['sirano'], $b['sirano']);
}
usort($json, 'order');

echo'<pre>';
print_r($json);
```

For descending change places `$b` abd `$a` variables:

```php
return version_compare( $b['sirano'],$a['sirano']);
```

Comment: The idea of version_compare is good as long as there are no more than 2 dots in the dotted numbers. For numbers like 1.21.7.8.6 the behavior is undocumented.

Comment: Yes it is true.) I wrote this answer only just condition as simple way. Thanks for information.

Comment: Nailing is easy!
Of course, the most valuable thing is to know where to shot.

Cheers!
Thank you.

Comment: Here you are)))

Answer (score 0):

```
uasort($array, fn($a,$b) => strnatcmp($a['sirano'],$b['sirano']));
```

[uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) keeps the original keys and [strnatcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) compare 2 strings using a "natural order" algorithm.